# Multiple try catch in a while loop

Tags: java, try-catch

Hopeing someone can help. Been trawling for days and cant find a solution.  Trying to create a `while` loop with a `try`/`throw`/`catch` for exception handling, but need to catch multiple exceptions.

I've tried just about everything I can think of it either doesn't come out the loop or it skips the rest of the code (not pasted here) and finishes the program.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean NotCorrectInput = false;
howManyToAdd = 0;

while (!NotCorrectInput) {
    try {
        System.out.println("How many products would you like to add?");
        howManyToAdd = scanner.nextInt();
        NotCorrectInput = true;
        }
    catch (InputMismatchException e){
        System.err.println("You have not entered the correct number format. Please try again.");
        }

    try {
        if (howManyToAdd < 1) {
        throw new NegativeArraySizeException();
        }
        } 
    catch (NegativeArraySizeException e) {
        System.err.println("You have not entered a possitive number. Please try again.");
        }

    }

    SecondProduct lp[] = new SecondProduct[howManyToAdd];
 //Rest of code from here on down.
```

I would like it to expect an `int` but if it is passed a `double` or a `float` then it will handle that in the loop and keep going until it is passed an `int`, but also if it is given a negative number to start off the array then it will loop back to the start and ask for a positive `int` to be passed.

Comment: You don't need try/catch - you can just use if statements.

Comment: Also, it is possible to catch multiple exceptions in a single try block: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html

Comment: You should choose your identifiers more wisely: `NotCorrectInput` actually contains the negation of what you'd expect. Most IDEs allow you to rename every occurence of a variable at once.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to throw any exception :

```
while (!NotCorrectInput) {
    try {
        System.out.println("How many products would you like to add?");
        howManyToAdd = scanner.nextInt();
        if (howManyToAdd >= 1)
            NotCorrectInput = true;
        else 
            System.err.println("You have not entered a positive number. Please try again.");
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.err.println("You have not entered the correct number format. Please try again.");
        scanner.next();
    }
}
```

BTW, `NotCorrectInput` is a confusing name, since you actually set it to true when the input is correct.

Comment: This is awesome.  Really helped thanks.  One adjustment that I had to do is within the catch statement I needed to add a scanner.next(); to clear the scanner from how many to add, otherwise it looped.  But thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (!NotCorrectInput) {
    try {
        System.out.println("How many products would you like to add?");
        howManyToAdd = scanner.nextInt();
        NotCorrectInput = true;
        if (howManyToAdd < 1) {
        System.err.println("You have not entered a possitive number. Please try again.");
        }

       }
    catch (InputMismatchException e){
        System.err.println("You have not entered the correct number format. Please try again.");
        }


    }
```

Thats how you do multiple try catch!

Comment: you can use it like that too.   catch (IOException|SQLException ex)

Comment: You can! But not if you have different messages for each exception

Comment: actually yes! makes sense

Answer (score -1):

Just adjust your code a bit:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean CorrectInput = false;
howManyToAdd = 0;

while (!CorrectInput) {
    try {
        System.out.println("How many products would you like to add?");
        howManyToAdd = scanner.nextInt();
        if (howManyToAdd < 1) {
            throw new NegativeArraySizeException();
        }
        else
            CorrectInput = true;
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e){
        System.err.println("You have not entered the correct number format. Please try again.");
    }    
    catch (NegativeArraySizeException e) {
        System.err.println("You have not entered a possitive number. Please try again.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Because that's what the op wanted: getting the try/catches working. I wouldn't even implement that in this way, but that's not "find another solution" task. Thanks for downvoting though.

Comment: if he wants to make something in the wrong way you show how to?? if OP wants to throw exception show him how to handle in the right way... throwing an exception for that does not makes any sense